# Draw tick mark in QTree

Tags: c++, qt

I want to draw a tick mark in a Qtreeview. I don't want to have a checkbox but just to indicate an item. Is there a way to do so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model's data() function, return a QIcon or QPixmap for the Qt::DecorationRole:

```
QVariant MyItemModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    ...
    if(role==Qt::DecorationRole)
    {
        if(currentItem.isChecked()) return QPixmap(":my_check_icon.png") // Checkmark Image
        else return QVariant(); // No checkmark
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi.. thanks for the reply.. But I want to paint the check pic when the user right clicks and select a menu item. I have created a function, 
void mycheck(QModelIndex index){


}
which ll be called from the menuevent. So is there a way to paint the icon with the QModelIndex index? Sorry for not explaining the question...